# How to calculate Silhoutte score for the data in excel sheet which are 2000 location coordinates or Eucledian distance

Tags: python, coordinates, cluster-analysis

How to calculate Silhoutte score for the data in excel sheet which are 2000 location coordinates or Eucledian distance. I need to cluster using k means algorithm based on the result from silhoutte method.

Comment: Did the answer help you? @Sudeesh

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are working on `iris` dataset (due to you haven't added a data sample). `SKlearn` library provides an easy way to cluster and evaluate clusters using different methods. One of those is `silhouette_score` which you can read about it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score). The implementation would be something like following:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
#
# Load IRIS dataset
#
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
#
# Instantiate the KMeans models
#
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=42)
#
# Fit the KMeans model
#
km.fit_predict(X)
#
# Calculate Silhoutte Score
#
score = silhouette_score(X, km.labels_, metric='euclidean')
#
# Print the score
#
print('Silhouetter Score: %.3f' % score)
```

output:

```
Silhouetter Score: 0.553
```

Moreover, there is a fantastic tutorial on "Selecting the number of clusters with silhouette analysis on KMeans clustering" [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) which you can use. Welcome to SO:P

**UPDATE1**

I modified the format of data to be fit for CSV files, then read it into a data frame object (which is more suitable for working with tabular data). After these steps, everything would be identical to the above implementation. What you should do is "trying different sets of hyper-parameters and choose the one(s) which accommodate your needs in the best way"

Data in CSV format:

```
Center Name Latitude    Longitude   Distance(km)    
C1  33.6350809  102.1806663 4.4895
C2  33.6361485  102.1505465 1.8717
C3  33.6361485  102.1505465 1.8717
C4  33.6244151  102.1895434 5.6702
C5  33.6471608  102.128043  0.5641
C7  33.6719763  102.1147108 3.4214
C8  33.6460824  102.1355122 0.1597
C9  33.6356565  102.1926811 5.5573
C10 33.6642832  102.1461243 2.3615
```

reading coordinates into `X` variable:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ll.csv', sep='\t')
X = df[['Latitude','Longitude']].values
```

The rest of the work:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=42)
km.fit_predict(X)
score = silhouette_score(X, km.labels_, metric='euclidean')
print('Silhouetter Score: %.3f' % score)
```

output:

```
Silhouetter Score: 0.473
```

**UPDATE2**

Based on what you have sent to me, the problem can be solved like this:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
df = pd.read_excel('For Clustering.xlsx')
X = df[['Reference Latitude','Reference Longitude']].values
for number_of_clusters in range(5, 16):
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=number_of_clusters, random_state=42)
    km.fit_predict(X)
    score = silhouette_score(X, km.labels_, metric='euclidean')
    print('Number of Clusters: %s\tSilhouetter Score: %.3f' % (number_of_clusters, score))
```

and the output:

```
Number of Clusters: 5   Silhouetter Score: 0.451
Number of Clusters: 6   Silhouetter Score: 0.460
Number of Clusters: 7   Silhouetter Score: 0.448
Number of Clusters: 8   Silhouetter Score: 0.450
Number of Clusters: 9   Silhouetter Score: 0.430
Number of Clusters: 10  Silhouetter Score: 0.425
Number of Clusters: 11  Silhouetter Score: 0.431
Number of Clusters: 12  Silhouetter Score: 0.435
Number of Clusters: 13  Silhouetter Score: 0.432
Number of Clusters: 14  Silhouetter Score: 0.442
Number of Clusters: 15  Silhouetter Score: 0.442
```

This indicates the best value for cluster count is `6`

Comment: The following is the data set.  Site (Location) ; Latitude ; Longitude ; Distance between DC and each location (km)
DC 33.6456589 102.1338637 0
C1 33.6350809 102.1806663 4.4895
C2 33.6361485 102.1505465 1.8717
C3 33.6361485 102.1505465 1.8717
C4 33.6244151 102.1895434 5.6702
C5 33.6471608 102.128043 0.5641
C6 33.6471608 102.128043 0.5641
C7 33.6719763 102.1147108 3.4214
C8 33.6460824 102.1355122 0.1597
C9 33.6356565 102.1926811 5.5573
C10 33.6642832 102.1461243 2.3615
C11 33.6469193 102.1995563 6.0826

Comment: need a program to capture these 2006 data and calculate silhoutte score

Comment: Would you please add your data, or a portion of it? @Sudeesh

Comment: Site (Location) : Reference Latitude ; Reference Longitude ; Distance between Distribution Centre  and each location (km)
C1 33.6350809 102.1806663 4.4895
C2 33.6361485 102.1505465 1.8717
C3 33.6361485 102.1505465 1.8717
C4 33.6244151 102.1895434 5.6702
C5 33.6471608 102.128043 0.5641
C6 33.6471608 102.128043 0.5641
C7 33.6719763 102.1147108 3.4214
C8 33.6460824 102.1355122 0.1597
C9 33.6356565 102.1926811 5.5573
C10 33.6642832 102.1461243 2.3615

Comment: Must read the dataset into `panda`'s data frame object, then everything would be straightforward @Sudeesh

Comment: Not familiar with pandas and python code to calculate silhouette score. Can u pls send me the code to pull my data? In excel file there are 4 columns.. 1st column is site name. 2nd and 3rd are its location coordinates. 4th column is the distance in km from a reference location to each of these sites.. There are 2006 such sites. I need to cluster these site based on the best silhouette score.

Comment: Add first 10 lines (or so) of your data @Sudeesh

Comment: I can mail u the complete set of data. can u pls quote ur mail id sir?

Comment: mehdi_j94@outlook.com @Sudeesh